# Software Floating Point Library for Arm aarch64

Tags: floating-point, arm, 64-bit, arm64, fpu

I am working on armv8 Cortex A55 with 5 cores ,in aarch64 mode and compiling with armclang. However my core doesn't have a hardware FPU unit but my program does have floating point operations. I need to use a SW FPU library consistent with the IEEE standard for arm aarch64 since armclang doesnt provide one for aarch64.

1. Will using  -mfloat-abi=soft be enough to tell the compiler not to use fpu instructions or registers anywhere?
2. How is the soft float abi option different from  -mgeneral-regs-only compiler option ?

Comment: I have tried with one library and facing a lot of issues and hence thought of asking the questions. Please take a look at questions 2 and 3 too. @NateEldredge

Comment: Edited now. Added the recommendation question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85455/floating-point-library-for-arm-aarch64

Comment: I don't think you can even use `-mfloat-abi=soft` for aarch64, it's aarch32 only.  I couldn't find any indication that anyone has even written a standard ABI for aarch64 without floating-point.  Although technically optional, it's a pretty central feature of ARMv8-A, and my impression is that ARMv8 devices without floating point are considered kind of obscure.

Comment: Using `-march=armv8-a+nofp+nosimd` is probably a little better than `-mgeneral-regs-only`.  But either way, it won't magically let you use floating point on your no-fp machine, with or without a library: it will simply make the compiler error out if you use floating point anywhere in your program.

Comment: As I said for a previous question, I think realistically your options are (1) rewrite all code in your program that uses FP (and `-march=...+nofp+nosimd` will enforce that for you), or (2) get better hardware.  Even if you do find a software FP library, the performance is likely to be disastrous if you are using it for anything more than computing a `12.34% done` progress indicator.